# Как сделать выпадающий список вариатнов поиска в SearchView

Tags: android

Как сделать выпадающий список вариатнов поиска в `SearchView`?

Вот по такому типу, когда человек  начал что то вводить, показывают варианты поиска.

[image: выпадающий список в SearchView]

Comment: Вот тут смотрели? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19990962/3212712

Comment: Не-а, спасибо , посмотрю, отпишусь.

Answer (score 1):

Слушатели

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

                        return true;
                    }


                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                        loadHistory(String query) ;
                        return true;
                    }
                });
```

С помощью этого метода можно отобразить выпадающий список. Когда хотим добавить или удалить данные, то добавляем и удаляем их в слушателях, но не забываем обновлять адаптер.

```
private List<String> items;
items = new ArrayList<>();

        //проверка
        items.add("test 1 ");
        items.add("test 2");
        items.add("Марина");

    private void loadHistory(String query) {

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {

            // Cursor
            String[] columns = new String[] { "_id", "text" };
            Object[] temp = new Object[] { 0, "default" };

            MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(columns);


            for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {

                temp[0] = i;
                temp[1] = items.get(i);

                        cursor.addRow(temp);
            }


            searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(newExampleAdapter(MainActivity.this, cursor, items));

        }

    }
```